# reindex required on product save magento

Tags: magento

when the new products get uploaded they are not visible on the front end. They told me we need to re-index every time. However re-index gets stuck.Please look into this issue for me and let me know if we can have it reindex automatically.

Reindex mode is Update on save and currently showing processing in index management

Answer (score 1):

If it shows as processing then it's probably running. It may take a long time depending on how many products you have. The core url rewrite index is the most intensive. The reason you need to index is most likely because you have enabled the Use Catalog Flat Tables options under system configuration which is good for performance and speed of the site. Downside is you need to re-index these flat tables when you add new items. You can have the indexes run automatically by configuring cron to call magentos index process.

e.g.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magentosite/cron.php
5 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magentosite/shell/indexer.php --reindex all
```

If it is stuck and you are sure it's not running, then you can change the status of the index process back to pending manually in the database by editing the table index_process. Re-run it manually from the admin and see if it fails. The index most likely causing your products not to show up is Flat Catalog Product Indexes so run this one first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When you insert new product so re-indexing is require and also disable you magento cache.
and also flush your magento cache.